# PHP Gallery writing out created thumbnails

Tags: php

Hey I'm currently working on a gallery system , and the filenames get stored in the database as i upload pictures.I'm wondering how i can write out all of the thumbnails being created from the original pictures at once in the document.

Currently i'm writing like this.

```
<td><img src="bilder/<?=$photo['filename']?>
```

but then i only get the original picture? anyone have any ideas?

Comment: <td><img src="bilder/<?=$photo['filename']?>"

Comment: Please post more codes in your question (not in comment). Too little code to diagnose the issue

Comment: You need to close your `<img>` tag, ie `" />` -> `<img src="bilder/<?=$photo['filename']?>" />`

Comment: OP needs to close its `<td>` tag as well.